# Table or view not found inserting into mysql that exists in Pyspark

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to Insert into an existing Mysql table using Pyspark JDBC connection however I get the following error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 384, in sql
    return self.sparkSession.sql(sqlQuery)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 545, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Table or view not found: test_write; line 1 pos 1'
```

Can I get assistance on this error. The table exist in the MySql Database, I was successful in Inserting with a Dataframe when selecting data form another table , however i would like to Insert directly to the Mysql database table.

My code:

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
import logging 

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test_conn").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)

hostname = "localhost" 
dbname = "dev_db"
jdbcPort="3306"
username = "******"
password = "********"
jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}?user={3}&password={4}".format(hostname,jdbcPort, dbname,username,password)

logging.info("***********Begin Writing***********")

sqlContext.sql(""" INSERT INTO test_write VALUES ('45','names',123455) """).write.format('jdbc').\
    options(url=jdbc_url,driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',dbtable="test_write").mode('append').save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Table or view not found exception` happened because you not registering the input dataframe as a TempView or a Table in spark sql.

to answer for your scenario is,

launch the pyspark(tested the below in spark 2.2.1 version) with `pyspark --packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38`
copy paste the below code sample, This would most likely just work. But this depends on your mysql set-up, so if it doesn't try changing password, username, db-url and other settings.

**1. ddl creation in mysql**

```
create database if not exists employees;
use employees;

CREATE TABLE departments(
dept_no CHAR(4),
dept_name VARCHAR(40));

describe departments;

/*
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dept_no   | char(4)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dept_name | varchar(40) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------|
*/
```

**2. loading data from spark to mysql**

```
import os
import logging 
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test_conn").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)

#input data in python list
input_row=[['d010', 'FinanceHR']]

#define input schema and create dataframe
cSchema = StructType([StructField("dept_no", StringType()),StructField("dept_name", StringType())])
df = spark.createDataFrame(input_row,schema=cSchema) 

#registering a tempview
df.createOrReplaceTempView("test_write")

sqlContext.sql("select * from test_write").show()
'''
+-------+---------+
|dept_no|dept_name|
+-------+---------+
|   d010|FinanceHR|
+-------+---------+
'''
#writing to mysql

sqlContext.sql("select * from test_write").write.format('jdbc').options(url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees",driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",dbtable="departments",user="spark",password="spark").mode('append').save()
'''
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]
'''
```

**3. data validation in mysql:**

```
login to mysql and validate the data loaded `| d010    | FinanceHR |`

mysql> select * from departments;
/*
+---------+--------------------+
| dept_no | dept_name          |
+---------+--------------------+
| d010    | FinanceHR          |
+---------+--------------------+
*/
```

**Notes to be taken,**

You don't insert into dataframes, they are immutable and lazy. you can't perform insert data into the temporary table or view in spark sql, but we can mimic the insert with `union all` (or) `union`(to remove duplicates).

1.please register your dataframes as a temp views using `createOrReplaceTempView` and try to load the data to datasources if you are going to use `spark.sql`

2.RDD/DF/Datasets are immutable by build so you cannot insert data to existing RDD/DF/Datasets in Spark. you can only transform an existing RDD/DF/Datasets into a another.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way of Inserting values directly into the Mysql Table?

Comment: are you generating a data in spark or you are reading a data from external datasources?

Comment: I am generating the data in the spark job

Comment: generate the data as a python list and create dataframe and register as a `createOrReplaceTempView` and select and write it to your mysql database.

Comment: Do you have an example.

Comment: updated the answer with working tested example on spark to mysql insert

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I appreciate it, I have just one last question: Can I populate the list with parameter  from the spark job or can I pass those Values in the CreateDataframe function?